# How can determine to run a script using `python` or `python3` depending on the installed version of python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell

I have a script file `myfile.sh` and contains the following

```
#! /bin/bash

set -e

MYVAR=`cat $1 | python -c 'import os`'
```

The question is, how I can make a condition to use python3 if python3 is installed or in other word(python is > 3) and use python if the installed version of is < 3
something like:

```
#! /bin/bash
set -e
#  CONSIDER THIS SUDO CODE 
if 'python3 --version' !== 'command not found or something null'; then     # SUDO CODE
  PYTHON=python3
else
  PYTHON=python
fi

MYVAR=`cat $1 | PYTHON -c 'import os`'
```

Comment: You could use the 'command' command

Comment: Does [this other Q&A help?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/289011)

Comment: It's not your script's job to worry about this. Use `python`, and document that the person *running* your script needs to have an appropriate `python` command in their environment. (Most likely, they will use a virtual environment created with whatever version of Python is deemed appropriate.)

Comment: At most, I would require the user to set `PYTHON` in the environment to an appropriate name (for path lookup) or path (relative or absolute) to the desired interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

The `command` command would allow you to check if `python3` is available and use it.

for example in the below script `python3` will be used and if not possible it will use `python`:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

if command -v python3 &>/dev/null; then
    PYTHON=python3
else
    PYTHON=python
fi

MYVAR=$(cat "$1" | $PYTHON -c 'import sys, os; print("Hello from", sys.version)')

echo "$MYVAR"
```